What kind of Present Participles are "Continuing,… ”, ”Walking along …”?
I came across some present participles (e.g., continuing, walking along, going, looking, and excluding), but they don’t seem to represent reasons or actions happening simultaneously. Could you explain what type of present participle these are and how they function?
1 :Continuing

one away from the rush of the shopping centre. There is a great deal of bicycle traffic, mainly undergraduates who race along thoughtless of safety, with long scarves (in various colours to denote their College) wound round their necks.
Continuing, I find my way to theriver which flows behind the College buildings and curls about the town in the shape of a horseshoe. This narrow river (a good jumper could almost leap it) is the Granta, and a little farther on it changes its name to the Cam.

2:  walking along

The walls rise out of their own reflection in the water and their colour contrasts charmingly with glimpses of the many green lawns. Walking along the river-bank, where the only sound is the noiseofthe gentle wind in the tree-tops, I come to my College, King's College. Across a bridge and beyond a vast carpet of green lawn stands King's College Chapel,

3: "going " and 4) looking down

The Colleges join one another along the curve of the river. Going through a College gate one finds one is standing in an almost square space of about
70 yards (the size varies from College to College) known as a "court". Looking down into the court on all sides are the buildings where the students live.

5: Excluding

The student gets a good impression of all the English architectural styles of the past 600 years-—the bad as well as the good.
There are nineteen Colleges, excluding two for women students, which were built near the end of the last century (women students do not play a very active part in University life at Cambridge


Excluding is like a preposition (Wiktionary calls it a preposition), but there's still simultaneity between the ones you're excluding and the number you have left. The rest of them all seem to describe things that happen at the same time as other things. Can you explain what you think is happening in each passage, and why you think it's not simultaneous?

The first four simply mean "as I continue (to walk)"' "as I walk along", "as I go" and "as I look" - the writer describes what they see while walking round Cambridge.

What @KateBunting said. They're just (continuous participle-based) adverbial clauses.

What is "ving no reason" supposed to mean? Is there a typo there?

I've listed the various semantic relations of ing-clauses (to the matrix clause) in the second answer here. Perhaps this helps. Simultaneity and purpose/reason are two (three?) of many possibilities.

Dear kate:  Your answer satisfied me. That's how I understood it. the participial phrases are more about narrative flow, scene-setting, and descriptive detail, rather than expressing simultaneity, consequence, reason, or condition. They're used to make the narrative smoother, and to immerse the reader in the environment and experiences being described

This is just standard verb stacking, also called serial verb construction. If the subject is carrying out multiple actions you can use verbs in succession within the clause to describe simultaneous (or sequential) actions. If they are all happening at the same time, or sequentially along with the narrative, then the tense of each verb will naturally be the same.
In a sentence like "I was continuing walking along, going about my business, looking around", all of the verbs are present continuous actions that are talking place. The speaker is continuing, they are walking, going about their business, and looking around. These things are all talking place as they walk.

I still have a question about present participles, and I’ve come across another example that I don’t fully understand. Could you please help me clarify it?"
1: Dropping my suit, I dashed downstairs to tell George.
2: Opening the drawer, he took out a revolver.
3: hearing the news, she fainted.
4 : Hearing the phone ring, I picked it up.
